# URL Reqrite in NGINX showing ip not url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want people to visit `www.mycharters.com.au` and for Nginx to proxy that request to `192.168.1.104:32400/index.html`.

My NGINX Config so far:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 $scheme://192.168.1.104:32400/web$request_uri;
    rewrite ^ http://www.mycharters.com.au permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` and `rewrite` statements are executed sequentially. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) for details.

So your `return` statement (which is not conditional) will always be executed, and any following `rewrite` statements will never be reached.

The `return` statement should always be the last statement in a chain of `rewrite` commands.

Possibly the functionality you are looking for is a `proxy_pass`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.